Describing Frequentist vs Bayesian probability using casual dialogue
I am trying to presented Frequentist and Bayesian probability in casual dialogue format (i.e. a discussion between friends) for my younger sister, who is unfamiliar. The goal of this exercise is to not to argue which framework is better, but rather to highlight the core differences.
I was hoping to get some feedback on whether (in an effort to reduce it to the essentials) I have made mistakes in presenting some of the philosophical standpoints.
The dialogue sounds super corny sometimes, sorry about that.

"My observed data ($x_1, ... x_n$)", said the Frequentist. "Is just one possible realization, selected by chance. There's nothing special about it. Instead, let's consider what happens if I was able to run my experiment again and again and again, realizing an infinite number of samples."
"Why would you want to do that?" asked his friend, the Bayesian.
"Why? Well, I could do all sorts of stuff! I could construct an estimator which guarantees the population parameter $\theta$ lies in it with near certainty i.e. 100(1-$\alpha$)% of realized samples. There is no sampling variability when I consider all the samples!"
"Yes, yes", said the Bayesian gently, as his friend had the tendency to start yelling when he got passionate about this topic. "But Freqy, you have only one sample". And it's quite small, he added in the privacy of his head.
"It doesn't matter," said the Frequentist. "Because the odds are in my favor. You see, suppose I construct a 95% conference interval. This means that for 95% of samples I realize, the CI I calculate will contain the true $\theta$! Oh sure, I will get unlucky occasionally, but if it's something really important I can make it 99% or 99.9%...whatever helps me sleep at night. And I can do the same for p values too..."
"I think," said the Bayesian quickly. "that it might not be the best approach to ignore the data you have actually collected, in favour of a thought experiment about repeated sampling."
"Well, how would you do it, then?" said the Frequentist brusquely. But he was also listening; he knew his friend was just as clever as he was.
"I'll start by first asking a question," said the Bayesian, "In your framework, do you believe there is a concept of absolute truth?"
"What do you mean?" asked the Frequentist.
"Do you believe," said the Bayesian, "that there is a probability of the true $\theta$ lying within a specific confidence interval like (0.53, 0.57), or the probability of the null hypothesis being true?"
"Of course not," said the Frequentist, "there's no uncertainty associated with these statements; they're either true or not true. You might as well ask if there is a probability that three is greater than five! It's just yes-or-no, not a probability.".
"Right," said the Bayesian, "that's what I mean by 'absolute truth'. You believe that there are some absolute facts that can not change: the true value of $\theta$, for example, or the fact that the null hypothesis is true (or not true)."
"I don't believe in absolute truth", continued the Bayesian. "I believe in evidence."
"My framework allows for evidence." said the Frequentist admonishingly. "I do actually use the realized sample, you know; it's not like I try to make claims out of thin air."
"That's not what I mean. I mean that: in a world without absolute truth, everything must have a relative value of truthfulness. Or else, it would be a very silly world, where nothing is true."
The Frequentist frowned. "You've lost me".
"Everything has a relative value of being true," persisted the Bayesian. "Let's take your gold watch, for example. You bought it from the jeweler downtown two months ago. It looks like solid gold. But there's a small chance the jeweler duped you and sold you cast-iron with gold leaf."
"It is solid gold." growled the Frequentist "Old Tessy is reliable. Also I've had it for a while, a fake would have worn out by now".
"That's exactly my point. Let's say on the first day, there was a small chance it was a fake. Say, 25%. Fine, 5%", said the Bayesian, as the Frequentist began to contest this. "1 in 20 chance that it was fake when you bought it. But in the last few months you've worn it, it hasn't flaked or lost color. Day by day you've gained evidence, and by now, you're almost certain that it's solid gold. Oh, maybe there's a one-in-thousand probability it's a very convincing fake, you can never be totally sure. But you're much more certain about it now than you were earlier."
"I suppose,", conceded the Frequentist. "I mean, I feel this way about cars: until I've driven them for six months I don't know if I have a lemon."
"That's what my framework allows: by the accumulation of evidence, we update how strongly we believe in a specific statement."
"Oh? And what is your 'evidence', exactly?"
"The same as yours; it's the realized sample ($x_1, ..., x_n$). I use each data-point to update my belief that any given statement is true. This is really powerful Freqy." the Bayesian's eyes were suddenly gleaming with excitement. "I could calculate the probability that a null hypothesis is true, or that the true $\theta$ lies in a specific interval like (0.53, 0.57), or just about anything. Of course, some evidence is stronger than others, but I have a way to adjust for that."
"But this could lead to anything!" shouted the Frequentist. "You could calculate the probability that the sky will fall tomorrow!"
"Yes, I could." said the Bayesian quietly.
They both looked up. It was a pleasant day. The sky, a clear blue expanse dotted with white clouds, showed no signs of falling anytime soon.
"There seems to be an issue with your framework," said the Frequentist, drawing his eyes away from it slowly. "You didn't tell me how you decided the initial probability was 5%."
"Oh, that", said the Bayesian with mild embarrassment. "Well, it seemed like a good enough starting point..."
"You mean, it's just a guess?" sneered the Frequentist.
"Intuition, rather". The Bayesian suddenly bristled. "It's not like your choice of 95% isn't intuition."
"Alright, alright, settle down." The Frequentist pondered the argument for a while. "I do admit this is more flexible. But aren't you concerned that people will find it confusing? If there's no absolute truth, what are you working towards by getting more data?"
"They will just have to trust that the framework will lead to a better understanding of the true value of $\theta$".
The Frequentist narrowed his eyes. "That sounds like dogma."
"No more dogmatic than believing $\theta$ is some number permanently woven into the fabric of the universe," said the Bayesian patiently.
"Oh come on, that's not dogma, that's just common sense!" exclaimed the Frequentist.
"We'll have to agree to disagree," said the Bayesian quickly, hoping to avoid a different argument.


The Bayesian didn't argue for coherency.

The dialogue sounds good to me. I'm not sure that's the best way to explain the subtleties between different statistical frameworks, but it's valid.

@GuillaumeDehaene I wanted a high-level overview which did not get too lost in the philosophical complexities (since the intended audience is a first-year undergrad). This is more entertaining, no?

It's a very different way of communicating the issues than what I would have chosen, but I'm rooting for your to succeed. Statistics needs to be explained better to people outside the fold (and probably people inside the fold: so many people misunderstand the basics). I commend you for sharing this.

@GuillaumeDehaene Thank you!

@ZackFisher do you mind posting this as a comment? Just the basic idea and how it links to the concept, not necessarily in a dialogue format.

I agree that you present some of the core ideas in an interesting way. A potential problem is that there's IMHO substantially larger diversity of viewpoints within each camp than the dialogue shows - especially in regards to which parts of the statistical underpinnings are treated as part of epistemology and which parts are considered simply as useful tools without deeper philosophical commitments. Obviously for an intro exposition, you need to remove some complexity, so ¯_(ツ)_/¯  You may (or may not) get better/more feedback on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

It seems to me that both the Bayesian and the Frequentist in this dialogue have a substantial degree of map-territory conflation.

These may be helpful: https://philosophy.cass.anu.edu.au/people-defaults/alanh/papers/rcp_your_problem_too.pdf https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10670-017-9936-9

I think, upon reflection, that your dialogue does a very good job of capturing a certain kind of important naive argument about probabilities - but I’m not sure it’s really good to keep framing the interpretation of probability as if it somehow fundamentally hinges on this particular argument.  The true picture is a lot more subtle, because probability is an inherently model-laden concept.  When we start trying too hard to figure out the “true” probabilities, we often end up asking questions that don’t mean anything.

The initial section before the "gold watch" example seemed to concentrate on parameter estimation, rather than testing.
For the watch example, the Bayesian seemed arguing that for "this particular" watch, there is a discrete parameter (TRUE, FORGED) being given a probabilistic belief, and the evidence gained through "day-to-day" use updates the belief. That sounds like sequentially collected data, a complexity that could be hard to understand initially, esp. when we think of how Freqy would hypothetically repeat the experiment.
For this discrete parameter, the discussion seemed having shifted from estimation to testing. If estimation were to be performed, the reported confidence/credible sets fall into only 2 categories: either a singlet set ({TRUE}, {FORGED}), or the full parameter space {TRUE, FORGED}, the latter not looking useful to me. But the earlier argument was that "I can make it 99% or 99.9%...whatever helps me sleep at night". I'm afraid that, for many confidence levels, Freqy's realized confidence set does not change at all, and could very often just be the useless full parameter space itself.
Therefore, I guess the discussion on the gold watch seemed all about testing, not estimation. But Freqy still faces the extra complexity due to the sequential nature of data accumulated, a complexity that causes more trouble to Freqy than to the Bayesian. The meaning of "99%" is harder to interpret in the sequential context.
With these technical nuisances and with the hope that later discussions will continue exploring differences in one topic (i.e., the estimation confidence at the beginning of the dialog), I think that probably an alternative example with a more familiar "continuous parameter" under non-sequential context could be better understandable to me (and hopefully to your sister as well).
